# Who sets $USER and $USERNAME environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables

Also, will these variables always match currently logged-in username (they do on my Debian system)? Can I assume their availability in other Unix(-like) systems?

I'm also curious why one would use `whoami` instead of just reading any of these variables.

Comment: Looking at the `man` page, `whoami` reports the name associated with your effective user ID. Which means it will return something different if you're using `sudo` or running a setuid executable. If you have `sudo` set up, try `sudo whoami` for example.

Comment: `USER` and `USERNAME` are ordinary environment variables, which means that, if you want, you can set them to arbitrary values. Just type `USER=xyz`. In other words, even if those variables exist, there is no guarantee that their values match the currently logged-in username.

Comment: @Uwe By `guarantee`, I meant by default (i.e. assuming user did not change them).

Comment: @Tshepang As a follow up to my first comment: compare the results of `sudo whoami` and `sudo echo $USER`

Comment: @JosephR. For `sudo echo $USER`, the shell expands `$USER`, *then* calls `sudo`. So of course it doesn't produce the same output as `whoami`. Like `sudo whoami`, `sudo sh -c 'echo $USER'` does (typically) output `root`. Regarding [your comment about `whoami` using the EUID](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76354#comment111564_76354), note that `sudo whoami` would output `root` even if `whoami` used the UID. `sudo` sets *both* EUID and UID for the command it runs (except in the very unusual situation that you explicitly configure it to behave otherwise). Compare `sudo id -u` to `sudo id -ru`.

Answer (score 46):

It's **login**.

The Linux [login(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) man page says:

> The value for **$HOME**, **$USER**, **$SHELL**, **$PATH**, **$LOGNAME**, and
>   **$MAIL** are set according to the appropriate fields in the password entry.

The FreeBSD [login(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login&sektion=1) man page says:

> The **login** utility enters information into the environment (see
>   [environ(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=environ&sektion=7)) specifying the user's home directory (HOME), command
>   interpreter (SHELL), search path (PATH), terminal type (TERM) and user name
>   (both LOGNAME and USER).

The [NetBSD](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?login+1), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/login.1) and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/login.1.html) man pages say the same thing.

Here's the [source code](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/v2.25.2/login-utils/login.c#L1039) from the util-linux login:

```
setenv("HOME", pwd->pw_dir, 0); /* legal to override */
setenv("USER", pwd->pw_name, 1);
setenv("SHELL", pwd->pw_shell, 1);
/* ... */
setenv("LOGNAME", pwd->pw_name, 1);
```

Here's the [source code](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/9.1.0/usr.bin/login/login.c?revision=243808&view=markup#l596) from the FreeBSD login:

```
(void)setenv("LOGNAME", username, 1);
(void)setenv("USER", username, 1);
(void)setenv("PATH", rootlogin ? _PATH_STDPATH : _PATH_DEFPATH, 0);
```

Comment: On my Fedora 16 box, I have both `USER` and `USERNAME` set and your command only returns `LOGNAME`.

Comment: @JosephR., unfortunately I don't have Fedora on hands but I've looked into FreeBSD's sources as well, see UPD..

Comment: But this is obviously not the case on Fedora. All I'm saying is, `login` doesn't seem to be the only thing setting these variables.

Comment: Note that Linux is just a kernel, it doesn't have a `login` command. OSes that use Linux as their kernel are free to use any implementation they like. For instance, Debian based systems tend to use the one from shadow-utils, not util-linux.

Comment: Note that `login` is often not invoked when logging in over `ssh` or by most graphical login managers.

Comment: @JosephR. `$USERNAME` may [be set by Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-USERNAME).

Answer (score 16):

There's no rule. Some shells like `tcsh` or `zsh` set `$LOGNAME`. `zsh` sets `$USERNAME` (you can even assign a value to the variable to change uids/gids to those of that user there if permitted to).

It may be set by some things that log you in like `login` (as invoked by `getty` when login on a terminal and sometimes by other things like `in.rlogind`), `cron`, `su`, `sudo`, `sshd`, `rshd`, graphical login managers or may not.

If there's been a login though, in my experience, `$USER` is generally set (but it may not be updated after a change of user id (via setuid commands) within that login session. POSIX requires that `$LOGNAME` be set upon login (and `cron`).

To get the login name portably, best is to use the `logname` command (if there's not been any login, it may return nothing). To get the user id, use `id -u`. To get one username corresponding to the current effective user id: `id -un`. To get all of them (most of the time, there's only one user name per user id, but that's not guaranteed):

```
perl -le 'while ($n = getpwent()) {print $n if getpwnam($n) == $>}'
```

Though that may not work on systems where the user database cannot be enumerated (as happens sometimes with networked user databases for instance).

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to rely on the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard here, since at some point in time you will probably care about not just user login (managed by the `login` program) but also `cron` jobs and the like.

Therefore, you should know that POSIX requires `$LOGNAME` but not `$USER`. E.g. `$USER` may not be set by cron, as pointed out in an [answer by Keith Thompson](https://askubuntu.com/a/802892/6130), which also references some history on how this relates to the history of System-V vs BSD:

> ... at least on my system (Ubuntu 14.04) the $USER environment variable is not set for cron jobs. Instead, you can use $LOGNAME, which is part of the environment for cron jobs.
>
> According to the [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) man page (type man environ to read it), $USER is used by BSD-derived programs and $LOGNAME is used by System-V-derived programs.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the environment variables (instead of `whoami` or `getpwent` and `getpwnam`) and you are unsure if they are always set the same way on all *NIX systems, then try this in bash:

```
THIS_USER=${USER:-${USERNAME:-${LOGNAME}}}
echo ${THIS_USER}
```

If it is still empty after all that, then you are on a rather esoteric system. ;)

Comment: All of these 3 variables are unset in a Docker container running `centos:7` and Host network.

Comment: Interesting. My centos7 docker image sets USER. It would seem that your centos7 image  never simulates running *login* to set those up. Hmm.

Comment: The `Dockerfile` does this:

    ENV user=foo
    USER ${user}
    WORKDIR /home/${user}

It works fine: "The USER instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the user group (or GID) to use when running the image and for any RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile."

Comment: If I want to use `USER` inside `ENTRYPOINT`, I can modify `Dockerfile`, I guess, to do `ENV USER=foo`. Just something to keep in mind...