# Shell script printing blank $USER variable when executed by Smartd

Tags: shell, shell-script, arch-linux, root, smartctl

I have created a script that smartd daemon (smartmontools) executes as per command below.

```
DEVICESCAN -a -m email -M test -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/my-script -n stand...
```

Smartd appears to be running as root looking at the top command output but it fails to find a config file in /root. $USER, $HOME, whoami, export USER=$(id -u -n) commands do not echo anything, not even an empty line. When executed manually in terminal it prints the current username as expected. Script was chmod'ed to 700.

Why is this happening?

Edit: Here is the actual script that I want to run.

```
#!/bin/sh

export USER=$(id -u -n)
echo $whoami
echo "USER: "
echo "$USER"
echo $HOME

EMAIL_EXEC="mailx"
EMAIL_ACCOUNT="gmail"
EMAIL_SUBJECT="simplified"
EMAIL_BODY="simplified"

echo "$EMAIL_BODY " | $EMAIL_EXEC -A $EMAIL_ACCOUNT -s "$EMAIL_SUBJECT" email@gmail.com
```

After restarting smartd errors are found in the log and no email is sent unlike if executed manually as root.

```
sudo systemctl restart smartd
journalctl -u smartd
```

Here is the output of journalctl log:

```
Test of /etc/smartmontools/run.d/email to email@gmail.com produced unexpected output (69 bytes) to STDOUT/STDERR:
USER:
root
Account `gmail' does not exist.
No mail for root
```

export USER=$(id -u -n) appears to have set the $USER variable as you mentioned. "gmail" is a profile in /root/.mailrc file. Same error is produced when running as non-root user because the .mailrc file is missing in users home.

How can I set the $HOME variable like the $USER variable? That might give an idea why it's not finding the file.

Comment: Related: [Who sets $USER and $USERNAME environment variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables)

Comment: Looked at the link, but unfortunately no alternatives to $USER variable produced different output.

Comment: The USER variable is set by the login program. Daemons don't have it in their environment. If your script needs to know the userid it's running as, one thing it can do is run the `id` command.

Comment: In particular, `export USER=$(id -u -n)`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that sounds like an answer, why not post it as one?

Comment: @terdon I can only answer one of his questions (and that question is basically a duplicate). I don't know why `whoami` would be printing nothing.

Comment: The reason I am using $USER is to determine what user the daemon is running under. I don't actually need to know the user as long as it is running as root but it doesn't appear to run as root. The real script fails because it cannot find the config file in the root's home. "export USER=$(id -u -n)" command prints nothing same like $HOME variable. I am assuming that the reason my script fails is the same as why I can't get the user variable printed.

Comment: @DominicM running a script as a user and running a command as a user are very different. The first runs in a non-interactive shell while the second runs in an interactive one. The two types of shell behave very differently. Please [edit] your question and explain the whole situation.

Comment: @terdon I simplified / clarified the question in the edit. I am not very familiar with shell scripting so I would like to hear more on how shell differs in interactive and non-interactive modes.

Comment: `export USER=$(id -u -n)` won't produce any output, but it will set the `USER` variable. Can you show us the code that is not working, for example, the code that tries to read the config file?

Comment: Sure, see edit.

Comment: Try adding `export HOME=~` . It's odd that `mailx` doesn't read `/root/.mailrc`. It does on opensuse, even when HOME is not set. I'll have to install arch to see why.

Comment: `echo $whoami` in your script will echo a blank line because `whoami` is not normally a variable. It is a standard command, though. `whoami` or `echo $(whoami)` should output a username.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick export HOME=~ printed "/root" and that actually fixed the problem completely! :) echo whoami just printed the literal string but echo $(whoami) printed the username, is that expected behavior? In any case I would love to know why variables are not being set on Arch Linux when executed by smartd, also are there any alternative fixes?

Comment: Just a line `whoami` - no echo, no $ - should print the username. The absence of $HOME is probably an issue with `systemd`, and the particular version of `mailx` you have  made it kind of a unique problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ultimate problem was that `mailx`, when called from a shell script run by `smartd`, started by `systemd`, on Arch Linux, was not reading the root user's `$HOME/.mailrc` file.

This was caused by a few factors:

- The `mailx` on Arch Linux, [s-nail](http://sourceforge.net/p/s-nail/code/ci/master/tree/main.c), relies on the environment variable `HOME` when looking for the `.mailrc` file. If `HOME` isn't present, it uses the current working directory.

```
  if ((cp = getenv("HOME")) == NULL)
      cp = "."; /* XXX User and Login objects; Login: pw->pw_dir */
  homedir = savestr(cp);
```

- `systemd` sets `HOME` only when the unit configuration file contains the `User` option.

  From [Environment variables in spawned processes](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes):

> $USER, $LOGNAME, $HOME, $SHELL
>
> > User name (twice), home directory, and the login shell. The variables are set for the units that have User= set, which includes user systemd instances.

Since there was no `HOME` variable in the environment provided to `smartd`, and it was likely started in the `/` directory, `mailx` didn't read the `/root/.mailrc` file.

To fix: add the line

```
export HOME=~
```

or

```
export MAILRC=~/.mailrc
```

to the shell script before it invokes `mailx`

or (not tested by me) add

```
User=root
```

to the `[Service]` stanza of your `smartd.service` unit configuration file.