# running as root but $USER returning regular user?

Tags: bash, users

So I was going to run a shell script but it's not working since it needs to be run as root. Thing is I'm logged in as root using the **su** command.

how is this possible?

```bash
root@polo-E15301:/home/polo/Downloads# echo $USER
polo      <<<---- regular user
root@polo-E15301:/home/polo/Downloads# whoami
root
root@polo-E15301:/home/polo/Downloads# echo $UID
0
root@polo-E15301:/home/polo/Downloads#
```

Comment: Perhaps you ran `su` instead of `su -`. See the man page for the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `su`ing to root specifically, `su` *doesn’t* set `USER` unless a login shell is requested; [`man su`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) says

> For backward compatibility, `su` defaults to not change the current
> directory and to only set the environment variables `HOME` and
> `SHELL` (plus `USER` and `LOGNAME` if the target *user* is not root). It
> is recommended to always use the `--login` option (instead of its
> shortcut `-`) to avoid side effects caused by mixing environments.

If you use `su --login` you’ll find `USER` is set to root.

In shell scripts, testing for root privileges should be done using a tool like `id` rather than relying on environment variables. See also [Who sets $USER and $USERNAME environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76354/86440)